# how to change value of an object using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to change the value of an object and pass the modified object.

Here is the object:

```
{
  id: '12497wewrf5144',
  name: 'ABC',
  isVisible: 'false'
}
```

Here is the code:

```
class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      demo: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('/api/random')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ demo: res.data})
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
{this.state.demo.map((user)=>
        <h1>{user.name}</h1>
        <input type="checkbox" value={user.value} />
)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Demo
```

I don't know what to write in onchange method for checkbox to only change the value within the object.

Note: value is string `isVisible` (we need to change value as boolean)

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Does it make sense defining *demo* in the constructor as an empty object when it looks like the fetched data using Axios is an Array?, I think It should be defined as an empty array e.g:
`this.state = {demo: [] }`

Answer (score 2):

In order to change a certain key of an object you can use the following

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  demo: {
    ...this.state.demo,
    isVisible: <NEW VALUE>
  }
})
```

Comment: It is important to note that when using the spread operator you do not have to define each and every property - only the properties that you want to update.

Comment: It looks like *demo* is an array in the end when fetching is done

Comment: Yeah, looks like he's updating each `user` in the array.

Comment: Yes, if its in an array then he might need to update the value at that specific index, I just gave him an overview how the state can be updated